# VS Code C# braces NOT on new lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, formatting, omnisharp, braces

Can't find a way to make formatters put braces on the same line. The default formatter seems to completely ignore all the settings related to new lines.

Some people recommended C# FixFormat extension, but now it's deprecated and gone from the marketplace. I also found [this extension](https://github.com/belav/csharpier), but it makes it clear from the very start that it's not gonna help.

```cs
Before

public class ClassName {
    public void CallMethod() { 
        this.LongUglyMethod("1234567890", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }
}

After

public class ClassName
{
    public void CallMethod()
    {
        this.LongUglyMethod(
            "1234567890",
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        );
    }
}
```

The default formatter seems to completely ignore the settings at all. I tried to put these everywhere ([as it was told here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1506#issuecomment-303390666)), but it only considers everything not related to new lines.

```json
{
    "MSBuild": {
        "UseLegacySdkResolver": true
    },
    "FormattingOptions": {
        "NewLine": "\n",
        "UseTabs": true,
        "TabSize": 2,
        "IndentationSize": 2,
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers": false,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors": false,
        "NewLineForElse": false,
        "NewLineForCatch": false,
        "NewLineForFinally": false
    }
}
```

I tried with: Manjaro Linux, VS Code, Microsoft C# extension, Dotnet 6

Comment: The default format vertically aligns braces, which makes sense to everyone except js and java developers. The default C style makes debugging much easier. May I politely ask you adapt to the C style for C, C++, and C#? :) I am biased to K&R C since 1988. I use the js convention when developing js code for distribution, when in Rome... Do as the Romans do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your **Visual Studio Code**, in the **C# extension settings**, make sure the ***Omnisharp: Enable Editor Config Support*** option (`omnisharp.enableEditorConfigSupport`) is enabled.

[image]

---

Then create a file named `.editorconfig` in your project directory with the following content:

```
[*.cs]
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
```

If the file already exists, modify or add the `csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none` line in the block for `[*.cs]` files.

---

In order to not have linebreaks before else, catch and finally, also add these lines:

```
csharp_new_line_before_else = false
csharp_new_line_before_catch = false
csharp_new_line_before_finally = false
```

---

If you want to apply the settings in all your projects, you can either

- place the `.editorconfig` file in a **common parent directory** of your project directories or
- place the `.editorconfig` file in the **home directory**. In Windows, this is the directory under %HOMEPATH%.

Comment: How do i set it up globally?

Comment: @Foresteam Extended the answer